# Input box opens when when cell changed to "complete"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet to track jobs. When staff mark a job as complete they are meant to fill in the total amount charged to the customer. However about 50% of the time they forget

Can I create a script that when they change the "status Column" to "Complete" an input box opens for them to fill in the $ amount and records it when they click ok in a corresponding column in the same row?

Comment: In the [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en) simple trigger you can check the address of the cell in which changes occurred, and using the [Browser.inputBox()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser?hl=en) method you can query the total amount from the manager

Comment: @Sergey You probably want to make an answer with that information (instead of a mere comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this script

```
SHEET_TO_WORK_ON = 'Sheet6'; // Please enter the name of your sheet here
STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER = 3;    // Enter the number of the column with the statuses here
CHARGED_COLUMN_NUMBER = 4;   // Enter the number of the column with the total amount charged here

function onEdit(e){
  let range = e.range,
      sheet = range.getSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() == SHEET_TO_WORK_ON && range.columnStart == STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER && range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == 'complete'){
    range.offset(0,CHARGED_COLUMN_NUMBER - STATUS_COLUMN_NUMBER).setValue(Browser.inputBox('Charged ', 'fill in the $ amount', Browser.Buttons.OK))
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome
When I use this on a test sheet I created it works perfectly. However when I try and add it to my main sheet that already has and onEdit in it i can not seem to get them to work together

Comment: Of course. You need to merge two onEdit() into one. Can you show the code of your original onEdit() or can you share your table?

Comment: Thanks for your help Sergey, Just after I posted my comment I was about to find the fault in my code that was causing it not to work.
It is working now, thanks

Comment: Is there a way to change the script so that it only opens the input box if the target cell (CHARGED_COLUMN_NUMBER) is empty